# Fill background color on UIButton while dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a custom `UIButton` with a blue background.
When I drag my finger over the `UIButton`, I need a red background color to be filled. When I drag my finger back, the red color should disappear.

I tried an implementation using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` state. Without adding another view on top of `UIButton`, I couldn't get red color in the button background.

Is there another way I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Add targets:

```
[button addTarget: self 
           action: @selector(buttonTouchStarted:withEvent:) 
 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragEnter | UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget: self 
           action: @selector(buttonTouchEnded:withEvent:)
 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragExit | UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchCancel];
```

And reposition a red overlay view in the control event handlers:

```
- (void) buttonTouchStarted:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint location = [[event touchesForView:button].anyObject locationInView:button];

    UIView *redView = [button viewWithTag:42];
    if (! redView) {
        // Install a red overlay
        redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        redView.alpha = 0.5f;
        redView.tag = 42;

        // IMPORTANT: We don't want this overlay view to block touches
        redView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [button addSubview:redView];
    }

    CGRect frame = button.bounds;
    frame.size.width = location.x;
    redView.frame = frame;
}

- (void) buttonTouchEnded:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *redView = [button viewWithTag:42];
    if (redView) {
        [redView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Not changing the background color in touch events. The background color should be live drawing while dragging. It's similar to selecting a word through cursor. Sorry if my question misleading you.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is that what you're trying to do? If not, it might help if you edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Sent Event properties` of the `UIButton` for the changing the drag time color use `TouchDragEnter` and for take back the same color use `TouchCancel`.

may be it helps you?